# Windows 10 WPF Xaml ListView Item Styles Not Matching Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-10

I have a WPF app that needs to support Win 7 and 10.  I can style ListView items ok and get the results I want, no mouseover or selection color at all ever, on Windows 7.  On Windows 10, it still highlights blue with mouseover or when touch scrolling.  Style and screenshots below.  Everything I find Googling this says I'm doing it right, but the highlight remains.  Assuming it is something slightly different for 10 that isn't popping up for me.

```
Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                         Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                         Color="Transparent" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Windows 7
[image]

Windows 10
[image]

Comment: You might want to make the question subject a bit more descriptive too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OS level things changed for 8 and 10.  Try something like this instead:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Border x:Name="Bd"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: That did it as-is.  Thank you!